# Teradata Window/Rolling Sum under Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, sum, teradata, cumulative-sum

I'm working in Teradata SQL Assistant 14.10 and running into issues with the following problem:

I have a list of calculated elapsed times, and I need to create a column that flags when

- a) the row for which the sum of the elapsed time exceeds 20 min for the first time
- b) the row for which the sum of the elapsed time exceeds 15 min for each time after that

The difficulty here being that the rolling sum that would be used to set the flag would needs to go to 0 after each condition(s) have been met. See the below result set with the FLAG being the desired output column based on the above conditions, and the reason column explaining why it is to be flagged.

```
RN  REPORT_DT   SEG_CD  NUM_F   T1          T2          ELAPSED_TIME    FLAG    REASON
1   6/22/2015   STATION 881     18:33:00    17:30:00    63              1       63 >= 20 min for first time
2   6/22/2015   STATION 881     18:45:00    18:33:00    12              0       12 < 15
3   6/22/2015   STATION 881     19:00:00    18:45:00    15              1       12 + 15 >= 15
4   6/22/2015   STATION 881     19:15:00    19:00:00    15              1       15 >= 15
5   6/22/2015   STATION 881     19:30:00    19:15:00    15              1       15 >= 15
6   6/22/2015   STATION 881     19:40:00    19:30:00    10              0       10 < 15
7   6/22/2015   STATION 881     19:50:00    19:40:00    10              1       10 + 10 >= 15
8   6/22/2015   STATION 881     20:00:00    19:50:00    10              0       10 < 15
9   6/22/2015   STATION 881     20:10:00    20:00:00    10              1       10 + 10 >= 15
```

I've tried a variety of SUM()OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY RESET WHEN) kind of queries which I feel is the right direction, but can't seem to get any desired results. 

Any advice is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alas, you cannot readily do this calculation with analytic functions.  The problem is that you have a remainder (such as 3 in your 3rd row).  You ignore this extra overage, meaning that subsequent rows have to know exactly where all previous breakpoints occurred.

Comment: Wow - thanks for the fast response.Appreciate to know it isn't possible, at least saves me from racking my brain all day again.

Comment: What's the number of rows and the max number of rows per PARTITION?

Comment: I would have just under 200k rows in total, and the above extract is the example of a single partition (I've partitioned over REPORT_DT, SEG_CD, and NUM_F). While each partition's row count is variable, I believe the largest one to contain 47 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I ever found to return a result like this utilizes recursion.

You will get the fastest speed if you materialize the data as a Multiset Volatile Table with the partition columns (REPORT_DT, SEG_CD, NUM_F) as Primary Index first and then start the recursion:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(   
SELECT
  RN,
  REPORT_DT,
  SEG_CD,
  NUM_F,
  T1,
  T2,
  ELAPSED_TIME,
  CASE WHEN ELAPSED_TIME >= 20 
       THEN 0 
       ELSE ELAPSED_TIME
  END AS sum_ELAPSED_TIME,
  CASE WHEN sum_ELAPSED_TIME = 0 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0
  END AS FLAG
FROM vt
WHERE rn = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  vt.RN,
  vt.REPORT_DT,
  vt.SEG_CD,
  vt.NUM_F,
  vt.T1,
  vt.T2,
  vt.ELAPSED_TIME,
  CASE WHEN cte.sum_ELAPSED_TIME + vt.ELAPSED_TIME >= 15 
       THEN 0 
       ELSE cte.sum_ELAPSED_TIME + vt.ELAPSED_TIME 
  END AS new_ELAPSED_TIME,
  CASE WHEN new_ELAPSED_TIME = 0
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0
  END AS FLAG
FROM vt 
JOIN cte 
  ON vt.REPORT_DT = cte.REPORT_DT
 AND vt.SEG_CD = cte.SEG_CD
 AND vt.NUM_F = cte.NUM_F
 AND vt.rn = cte.rn + 1
) 
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Comment: This is amazing - Thanks!